keep track of TCP client connection status
my current implementation contains a public propriety that is binded to a toggle button
{
    get => _isListening;
    private set
    {
        if (_isListening != value)
        {
            _isListening = value;
            OnIsListeningChanged?.Invoke(_isListening);
        }
    }
}

when the connection starts the IsListening is set to True
public static async Task StartListeningAsync()
{
    if (IsListening) return;
    IsListening = true;
    cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var serverAddress = Settings.Default.tcpIpAddr ?? "10.23.5.181";
    if (!int.TryParse(Settings.Default.tcpIpPort, out var port))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Port is not configured correctly.");
    }
    InitializeChannel();

    using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(serverAddress, port);
            Debug.WriteLine($"TCP CLIENT IS CONNECTED TO {serverAddress} PORT {port}");

\\this is a producer consumer pattern to treat the received messages from the server.
            var networkStreamTask = ProcessNetworkStreamAsync(tcpClient, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            var backgroundTask = Task.Run(() => ProcessQueueAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token), cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            await Task.WhenAll(networkStreamTask, backgroundTask);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"SocketException: {ex.Message}");
            MessageBox.Show($"The server refused the connection. Make sure that IP {serverAddress} and port {port} are correct.");
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Operation was canceled.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Error during startup: {ex.Message}");
            MessageBox.Show($"Error during startup: {ex.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            IsListening = false;
            await StopListeningAsync();
            FinalizeChannel();
        }
    }

when the cancellation token is passed the StopListeningAsync turn the isListening back to False.
this implementation sometimes have some bugs that I am not really able to isolate. for example sometimes the incoming messages from the server are stopped and no exception is recorded.
is there a way to keep track of the actual status of the connection to the server and bind it to my control in the UI?
edit:
private static async Task ProcessNetworkStreamAsync(TcpClient tcpClient, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        int bytesRead;
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested &&
               (bytesRead = await networkStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
        {
            string receivedChunk = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            messageBuilder.Append(receivedChunk);

            string fullMessage = messageBuilder.ToString();
            int delimiterIndex;

            while ((delimiterIndex = fullMessage.IndexOf('\n')) != -1)
            {
                string completeMessage = fullMessage.Substring(0, delimiterIndex);
                await EnqueueItemAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(completeMessage), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                fullMessage = fullMessage.Substring(delimiterIndex + 1);
            }

            messageBuilder.Clear();
            messageBuilder.Append(fullMessage);

            // Add a small delay to prevent tight loops
            await Task.Delay(10, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Network stream processing was canceled.");
        ErrorHandler.LogError(ex, "ProcessNetworkStreamAsync");
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Network stream IO error: {ex.Message}");
        ErrorHandler.LogError(ex, "ProcessNetworkStreamAsync");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Error handling client: {ex.Message}");
        ErrorHandler.LogError(ex, "ProcessNetworkStreamAsync");
    }
}


ProcessNetworkStreamAsync what does this do?

original post edited with the method ProcessNetworkStreamAsync. it basically enqueue all the messages from the tcp server to a channel to be processed by an async task (ProcessQueueAsync)

@federico. sometimes the incoming messages from the server are stopped and no exception is recorded How and where do you determine that the stream is "stopped"? It's when you do this that you need to set your property.

I think this may help tcpClient.Client has a Connected property.
